# Interprocess Communication in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I've got two questions regarding Linux programming:

- If a Unix process reads from a pipe but no data has been written to that pipe, what action does the kernel take in regard to the reading process?
- If a writing process then writes more data to the buffer than the reader has requested, where will any excess data (not delivered to the reader) reside?

Comment: (a) The reading process hangs until there is some data to read, or there are no processes left that could write to it.  (b) It'll be left in the pipe for the next read operation — or will be discarded when the pipe is closed by all readers.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question in case of a blocking file descriptor and the second question, what Jonathan Leffler wrote applies.
As for the first question in case of a nonblocking file descriptor, the Linux kernel just returns `-EAGAIN` (see [pipe.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/pipe.c#L311)).